# How do i tell the build was successful in AfterBuild target in msbuild?

Tags: msbuild

Basically, I would like to perform some tasks in AfterBuild target but only when the build is successful.

I read somewhere that PostBuildEvent is run after a successful build but AfterBuild is run regardless.  Is this true?

Answer (score 5):

`AfterBuild` target won't be called if the build is not successful.

It is defined like this in `$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Common.targets`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <BuildDependsOn>
    BeforeBuild;
    CoreBuild;
    AfterBuild
  </BuildDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If the build fails (`CoreBuild` target), `AfterBuild` won't be called.